# I want my table cells to overflow. How do I do that?

Tags: tables, makecell, overlap, overflow

I have a table that is coded like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{p{1in} p{3in}}
    \makecell[l]{Text in a \\ cell} & \makecell[c]{Text in \\ another cell} \\
    \makecell[l]{Another row} & \makecell[c]{Another row}
\end{tabular}
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Text i|n aText in  |
cell  |another cell|
------+-------------
Anothe|rA###her row| (# indicates overlapping characters)
```

I tried using `rlap`. This creates unwanted space. Code:

```
\begin{tabular}{p{1in} p{3in}}
    \makecell[l]{\rlap{Text in a \\ cell}} & \makecell[c]{\rlap{Text in \\ another cell}} \\
    \makecell[l]{\rlap{Another row}} & \makecell[c]{\rlap{Another row}}
\end{tabular}
```

Undesirable result:

```
Text i|n aText in  |
cell  |another cell|
      |            |
      |            |
------+-------------
Anothe|rA###her row|
```

Is this even possible with LaTeX, the `tabular` environment, and `makecell`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to understand what you're trying to do (and even harder to understand *why*...) but would simply using `\mbox` to prevent line breaks do the trick?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.20in}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1in}}
\mbox{Text in a}\linebreak cell & Text in\linebreak another cell \\
\mbox{Another row} & Another row\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: overlapping columns]

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted, because obviously I had to make the columns much narrower than you had in your code to achieve a result like this.